# Is their a way to execute column validators when cell values are modified using cell.setValue() function?

Tags: tabulator

It seems column validators are meant to be used only during user input. Is there way to apply them when the cell value is changed programmatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The cell setValue function is designed to force a value into the cell, Validators at present are only designed to be triggered by direct user interaction with the table.

Though this is an interesting idea, i will add it to the roadmap for consideration in a future release

Comment: Thanks Oli, for responding and for considering this as feature request. This is important for me because I want validators to run when pasting from clipboard. Also, thank you very much for providing this awesome piece of software.